# Push git sumbodule to own remote repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm new to git, so I need your help.

I have project, and I'm added some third-party libraries to it from GitHub using `git submodule add`. I have modified some libraries depending on my needs. So how can I push that libraries with all the changes to my remote repo? Or what can I do to have all that libraries in my remote repo? thanks.

Comment: Guessing, but: you're on your way to maintenance hell. You don't modify vendor-dependencies unless you want the burden of maintaining them yourself - you extend/override them. i.e. work with their original source untouched, so that you can "just" update when a new version is released.

Comment: thanks, it's iOS project, these libraries is some custom UI classes, and other tools, and contains only 2-6 files.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own fork of the library (and maybe send a pull request), then change the submodule to reference the fork.

Comment: thanks, can I do (or how can I do) this without loosing and rewriting my code? thanks again.

Comment: @SLaks that's strange advice. E.g: Fork on github, change origin in submodule to point at fork, push to fork, change .gitmodules to point at fork, done.

Comment: @AD7six: That's what I meant.

Comment: "in a separate folder", "copy your modifications" and "then commit them" imply something different i.e literally `cp -R foo foo_fork && cd foo_fork && git commit ..` etc. - I upvoted your answer already anyway though.

Comment: @AD7six: I hadn't realized that you could commit and push from inside a submodule.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Submodules are nothing more nor less than nested repositories; all the submodule command does is help schlep them around.  There's nothing special about a submodule repository, a submodule is just an ordinary repo whose contents are interesting to a project contained in some specific other repo.  So just push your submodule repos to github the same as you'd do for any other.